# Which error codes for SFTP error in Mulesoft 3

Tags: error-handling, mule, mulesoft

I have developed an application in mule3 to transform data and then upload the data as a file to sftp location. I have included all common errors, such as http 400 series and 500 but what is a proper handling status code for when ftp fails, for example with file upload, connection or permission.
I have searched a lot on the internet and the more I search the more I get lost.
Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a table for mapping error codes between SFTP and HTTP, there is no standard for it. These are completely different protocols. You have to define your own mapping. Most of them will probably be 5xx in HTTP, with authentication errors probably 403.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which connector version you use. But if you open the documentation of the SFTP connector, like: https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.4/sftp-documentation.

You can see the documentation refers to the error that could be thrown, for example the [copy operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.4/sftp-documentation#copy) can throw [the following errors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.4/sftp-documentation#throws).

Based on those errors you should do your logic. Also the [HTTP connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.6/http-documentation) is throwing such errors, but then in the HTTP namespace. If needed you can also remap errors to a different and new namespace. Based on your remapped errors you could also implement logic.